# Flag Active record in continuous form

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to find out how to flag the active record in a continuous form.  It would be nice to add a red box to the record that is active to help users to track where they are.  I found [this page](http://www.reocities.com/SiliconValley/7043/ccodes01.html) which claims to have solved the problem but the mdb is in a format that I can't  open or convert.  The continuous form that I am dealing with can have up to 300 lines.  This means that it is impractical to set a field and refresh without the whole screen flashing.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to set an unbound text box on the sub form to the primary key on the Current event of the subform.  Then use conditional formatting to set the back color of one or multiple textboxes based on whether the unbound text box equals the primary key.

[Here is more info](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0aadffc8-6867-4598-be7a-8d971df0e608/how-to-use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-current-record-on-an-unbound-datasheet-subform?forum=accessdev)